# How can I add variable number of UILabel dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, uiscrollview

I've searched here and googled to find the solution, but I couldn't find nothing.

My app will retrieve the variable number of text string of the item's name and text string of the item's value from the web in JSON format.

The problem is that how many sets of name and value will be returned until I retrieve them from WEB API. Let me call the returned sets count as "n".

What I want to do is dynamically generate n UILabels dynamically and put them on UIScrollview with constraints, and also I want to set the height of UIScroll view to the necessary to "n".

And I need to show this View as a pop over.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest u use UITableView w/ reused cells instead, there're many resource available about how UITableView works. :)

Comment: use cellforindexpath uitableview for counting, or json array count,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use a UITableView. Give the data source array of the table view as the array of details you get from web service. And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, assign values for the UILabel of the cell

Comment: Thank you so much. That sounds the best solution.

I'll try it tomorrow.